# Open play store app through push notification using Parse.com android

Tags: android, google-play, parse-platform

I want to start google play through push notification using Parse.I am sending url through json using Parse Dashboard and getting it too. I tried a lot with broadcast receiver but get nowhere. So a little help or hint would be appreciable

**Code**

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("MyAction");

pushReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String message = extras != null ? extras.getString("com.parse.Data") : "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
            String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + url));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + url)));
            }                                             
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(pushReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: "I tried a lot with broadcast receiver" - What have you tried? Post your code, the expected result, and what actually happened.

Comment: it is like just app playstore updation if user did not update his app. I want check if I can do it by myself too using parse? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Tanis.7x actually code what I tried with debugger is working fine. The problem is when I am trying it without debugging , it simply opens the page which I set in Application. code is called from onstart().

Comment: "it is like just app playstore updation if user did not update his app" -- the Play Store opens up in response to the user tapping upon a `Notification`, *not* in response to a push.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I edited. It is calling from onstart(). When I am debugging I am able to open playstore, but when I am not debugging it is opening the activity.

Answer (score 1):

What i found out from code is, if you don't do any magic by overriding *ParsePushBroadcastReceiver*'s *onPushOpen*, you can add an uri and an action via web setting the type of the message from *Text* to *JSON*. For example this one we use to send users to Play with an information about an available update (if there version is very outdated):

```
{
    "title": "<the title goes here>",
    "alert": "<the message goes here>",
    "uri": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package name>",
    "action": "android.intent.action.VIEW"
}
```

There is no need for code since *ParsePushBroadcastReceiver* is taking care of that (using Parse version 1.9.4)

Comment: since parse is about to shut down, i wanted to use this but it doesn't look like it's working. it just opens the main activity